# FFMPEG concatenation not working correctly

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a code for wav file concatenation using ffmpeg.

```
E:\vishnu>ffmpeg -f concat -i C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ConcateFile.txt -c copy C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new.wav
```

I will also include the contents of my ConcateFile.txt file.

```
file 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\5secemptyaudio.wav'
file 'D:\UNKNOWN_SNO\420_uncompressed.WAV'
```

Here my first file (5secemptyaudio.wav) has duration 5 seconds.

Second file (420_uncompressed.WAV) has duration 10 seconds.

After concatenation is done the duration of the output file is just 10 sec.

Please help me.

I will include the commandline output of my attempt

```
E:\vishnu>ffmpeg -f concat -i C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ConcateFile.txt -c copy C:\
Users\admin\Desktop\new.wav
ffmpeg version N-59036-g5d8e4f6 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 12 2013 22:01:01 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 58.100 / 52. 58.100
  libavcodec     55. 45.101 / 55. 45.101
  libavformat    55. 22.100 / 55. 22.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     3. 92.100 /  3. 92.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[concat @ 024f2800] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, concat, from 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ConcateFile.txt':
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1382 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, wav, to 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf55.22.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, 141
1 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
```

Comment: That's not the full uncut command line output. You can leave out the duplicated PTS messages, but please at least show the header (starting with "ffmpeg version ...") and show us the output of `ffmpeg -i C:\Users\admin\Desktop\5secemptyaudio.wav` and the same for the other file.

Comment: Not able to take the full uncut output since it is too long. I will include the main part.Input #0, concat, from 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ConcateFile.txt':
  Duration: 00:00:00:00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1382kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio:pcm_s16le <[1][0][0][0] /0x0001>,44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s

Output #0,wav, to 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\new.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT           : Lavf55.22.100
    Stream #0:0 Audio: pcm_s16le <[1][0][0][0] /0x0001>, 44100Hz, stereo, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 <copy>

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to include all the "invalid PTS" messages. Just the start with "ffmpeg version" until the error messages. And not in a comment, please, but by [edit]ing the original question -- otherwise it's just unreadable.

Comment: Sure slhck. I edited the original question

Comment: This isn't enough, unfortunately. We need 1) The output of `ffmpeg -i <first-file>` and `ffmpeg -i <second-file>`, and 2) The output of the concat command starting with "ffmpeg version..." until the end, but without the "invalid PTS" error messages

Comment: I edited again slhck.

Comment: We are still missing the information from your individual input files.....